# Using a Stripe::Card to create a new Stripe::Charge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a `Stripe::Card` for a customer, but I need to be able to put that into a `Stripe::Charge` since I can't call `Stripe::Charge.create source: the_card_i_have` because source needs to be a hash of the card's attributes.

Does the `ruby-stripe` gem have some sort of built in way to convert that card to a hash? Is there an easy way to do that or do I need to make a helper method to do that manually?

Comment: To create a charge, you'd either pass a hash of card details as source (which is not PCI compliant in most cases), or the id of a token created with Stripe.js or Stripe Checkout. If you previously saved a token to a customer, you can pass both the customer id and the card id to the create method. You could never pass a Stripe::Card to the create charge method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stripe::Card` has a `to_hash` method, it should do what you want:

```
Stripe::Charge.create source: the_card_i_have.to_hash
```